# Setting up jQuery function that takes variables attached to HTML onClick event

Tags: jquery, html, function, syntax, onclick

I'm trying to create an image slider plugin for wordpress. One of the things I'd like it to do is make images go fullscreen when you click on them.

In order to avoid the page having to load all the full size images on load, I'd like to call a jquery ajax function when the user clicks on the image.

So the plugin knows what image to load, the function takes a parameter of wordpress' attachment ID for that image, so the link would look like:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='fullscreen(123)'><img src="previewimage" /></a>
```

…which would basically just mean get the image with the ID 123 and display it.

The jQuery I have that isn't working looks something like this:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.fullscreen = function(id) {
    stage = $('#template-to-place-image-in');
    stage.css('display', 'block');

       $.ajax({
            // a bunch of ajax parameters that get the image with the requested id and then place it into the template
        });

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
};

}(jQuery));
```

Main problem is that when I try to click on the preview image, the javascript console gives me an error saying:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fullscreen is not defined
```

I'm quite new to javascript and jquery so I'm guessing this is a pretty simple syntax issue, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If someone can help it would be awesome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$.fn` you are creating a extra function for jQuery. so you can access him by using `$(mySelector).fullscreen()`.

There is no need for creating a jQuery function in this case.
Use the following Javascript code:

```
(function($) {

    window.fullscreen = function(id) {
        var stage = $('#template-to-place-image-in');
        stage.css('display', 'block');

           $.ajax({
                // a bunch of ajax parameters that get the image with the requested id and then place it into the template
            });

        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: This will cause the same `undefined`-error, because `fullscreen` is private to `function($) {}`. To use fullsreen in an `onClick`-attribute it must be declared **global**. Either remove the wrapping `(function($){}(jQuery))` then the code must be included **after** jQuery. Or set `window.fullscreen = fullscreen;` as last line into it to make it global.

Comment: @MartinErnst: Thanks! Forgot that. I updated the answer